# How to get failed token in firebase-php?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the firabase-php(https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) library to push notifications to multiple devices with flutter.

I have followed the following document and it is working fine:

https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html#send-messages-to-multiple-devices-multicast

Now, I want to remove failed tokens from DB if any, but not sure how to get them. The above document is showing how to get message for each request. Is there a way to get failed token? Something like $failure->error()->getToken()?

```
if ($report->hasFailures()) {
    foreach ($report->failures()->getItems() as $failure) {
        echo $failure->error()->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the following methods](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/blob/36257df2e380328eb06b7ef1663603b533486503/src/Firebase/Messaging/MulticastSendReport.php#L158):

```php
// Registration tokens that are valid, but not 
// known to the current Firebase project
foreach ($report->unknownTokens() as $token) {
    echo $token.PHP_EOL;
}

// Invalid (malformed) tokens
foreach ($report->invalidTokens() as $token) {
    echo $token.PHP_EOL;
}
```

I somehow missed adding this to the docs, but <strike>will do it soon</strike> [finally managed to do so](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/commit/a0ac2e5ae4b7dd35c9abe66b6baa8188238e93ef)